# How do I properly use NavigationView in a ZStack?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to add some filter options to sit at the top of my view, above the NavigationView. I wrote the following code that mostly does what I want, however it disabled the ability to click on the rows to get to the detailed view. I assume this is because my filter buttons are on top of the ZStack, but I'm not sure how else to get this to work.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BonusList: View {
    var bonuses = sampleBonusData
    @State var showSettings = false
    @State var showBonuses = false
    @State var bonusEarned = true
    @State var showStatePicker = false
    @State var showCategoryPicker = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                List(bonuses) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: BonusDetail(bonusName: item.bonusName, bonusCode: item.bonusCode, city: item.city, sampleImage: item.sampleImage)) {
                        HStack(spacing: 12.0) {
                            Image(item.sampleImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(15)

                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(item.bonusName)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.shield")
                                        .opacity(self.bonusEarned ? 100 : 0)
                                }
                                Text("\(item.city), \(item.state)")
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .frame(height: 25.0)
                                HStack {
                                    Text(item.bonusCategory)
                                        .font(.caption)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .padding(.top, 4)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(item.bonusCode)
                                        .font(.caption)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        .padding(.top, 4)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Bonuses"))
                //            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .saturation(self.bonusEarned ? 0 : 1)
            HStack {
                FilterByCategory(showCategoryPicker: $showCategoryPicker)
                Spacer()
                FilterByState(showStatePicker: $showStatePicker)
            }
            StatePicker(showStatePicker: $showStatePicker)
            CategoryPicker(showCategoryPicker: $showCategoryPicker)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like when I run it:

[image: Screenshot of what the app looks like when ran.]

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `navigationBarItems`?

Comment: @Asperi I have made that change, but it didn't fix the issue. The ZStack also contains the off-canvas menus that will pop in when those buttons are tapped. I suspect it is the ZStack causing the issue, just not sure how to work around it. Making your change did make it look better though, I didn't think to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a view or two which sit higher in the `ZStack` that are off canvas and come in when those buttons are tapped?

You could consider using a modal and setting the view you want to show for each button as the view for the modal. This will keep your views off screen and still allow interaction with your list. Here's what I've done...

**On the main view**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
               //...
            }
    //Modal
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                AddItem(showModal: self.$isPresented)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**The modal's view**

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddItem: View {

    @Binding var showModal: Bool

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showModal = false
                }, label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is correct. I will try what you are suggesting with the modal, though just to clarify: the buttons in the NavigationBar should trigger the Modal, not tapping on the rows in the table view.

Comment: @DJFriar - Yep, understood. Have your buttons as navigation items as mentioned above, and then those can control showing the modals. You then shouldn't need to include the `ZStack` and you'll be able to tap the rows.